# Clion-Function doesn't return the correct value

Tags: c++17, clion

Im a total beginner to C and decided to use Clion for an ide. Which didn't end up in a good way since when i tried my very first code it didn't return what it was supposed to or maybe there is a mistake i couldn't figure?

Here is the code:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
        x += i;
    return x;
}
```

Also im using C++17 and instead of 5050 it returns 186. I tried to change the return value to zero and print the x and for some reason it successfully printed 5050. Can someone explain me what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you looking at/ using/ printing your return value?

Generally the `main()` method in C++ is different from "normal" user-defined functions. It's called at startup and serves as the entry point to your program. Usually you would have other functions that you call from within your `main()` method. If your `main()` method returns `0` it means it executed successfully, Any other value means there was some error during execution. If you don't have a return statement and execution reaches the end of the method, it implicitly returns `0`, meaning the execution was successful.

I am not sure why the return value was 186 instead of 5050 (where did you see that value?), but your calculation is correct. If you write a method other than `main()` with this code it will return the correct value:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int calculate(int value) {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= value; i++) {
        x += i;
    }
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int result = calculate(100); // result will be 5050
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As i said, when i print or try to apply any function with the result it works fine, but for some reason whenever i try assign it as return value of the main function, it doesn't give 5050 but 186. Also i tried your code and it printed 5050 but when i changed the return value with the integer result it ended up with giving the 186 again.

Comment: The 'return' value in the main()-function is not meant to return a result. To put it very simple, it should always return '0'. Don't use it to show a number. Use the suggested code, if you want to show any number when running your program.